# How to separate with unequal column (reverse toString) in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tidyverse

I'm working with survey data trying to multiple responses in a single column. The problem is that there may be 1-5 answers, separated with commas.

How do I turn this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  splitThis = c("A,B,C","B,C","A,C","A","B","C")
)

> df
  splitThis
1     A,B,C
2       B,C
3       A,C
4         A
5         B
6         C
```

Into this:

```
intoThis <- data.frame(
  A = c(1,0,1,1,0,0),
  B = c(1,1,0,0,1,0),
  c = c(1,1,1,0,0,1)
)

 > intoThis
  A B c
1 1 1 1
2 0 1 1
3 1 0 1
4 1 0 0
5 0 1 0
6 0 0 1
```

Any wrangling help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `mtabulate` from `qdapTools` after splitting by `,`

```
library(qdapTools)
mtabulate(strsplit(as.character(df$splitThis), ","))
#  A B C
#1 1 1 1
#2 0 1 1
#3 1 0 1
#4 1 0 0
#5 0 1 0
#6 0 0 1
```

---

As the OP also mentioned `dplyr/tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
rownames_to_column(df, "rn") %>% 
          separate_rows(splitThis) %>%
          table()
```

Or using `tidyverse` packages

```
rownames_to_column(df, "rn") %>%
        separate_rows(splitThis) %>% 
        group_by(rn, splitThis) %>% 
        tally %>% 
        spread(splitThis, n, fill=0) %>%
        ungroup() %>% 
        select(-rn)
# A tibble: 6 × 3
#      A     B     C
#* <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1     1
#2     0     1     1
#3     1     0     1
#4     1     0     0
#5     0     1     0
#6     0     0     1
```

Comment: You are a genius and a scholar. Let me implement this and see if it works with my data. For some reason I thought `tibble` was a `Hadleyverse` package.

Comment: @Dan Yes tibble is part of that.  In the previous one, I got the results with `table` which is in `base R`, so I thought to use the `spread` etc.  Thank you for the generous comments.  I consider myself as learning everyday from questions from you guys and from great answers from others.

Comment: *cough* tidyverse *cough*

Comment: You are my hero